# Different footer position in different pages

Tags: spacing, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am creating document with headers and footers. The problem that I faced with is that I cannot get nice view of first and the other pages: different spacing is set. See my code and picture.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage
[
        a6paper,
        left=2.5cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=2.5cm,
        bottom=2.5cm,
]
{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{My Title \\ \today}
\rfoot{User Guide \\ version 1.0}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{blank.png}}
\rhead{\thepage}
%\setlength{\headsep}{1in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use this new one to replace the old \lhead

```
\lhead{
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{fig}
\end{picture}
}
```

without changing headheight and the figure size.

image 1[image]

image 2[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your example I changed `\includegraphics[width=1cm]{blank.png}` to `\rule{1cm}{1cm}`. After compiling, I found the following warning in the log file.

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 32.05278pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Adding `headheight=33pt` to the options for the `geometry` package eliminated the problem. You may need a different height if `blank.png` is not exactly square.